# Azure Node.js Table Storage Query Not Returning Wanted Results

Tags: node.js, azure, sdk

I'm using Azure Node.js SDK and am having trouble getting this query to work:

```
var ts1 = azure.createTableService(config.storageAccount, config.storageAccessKey, config.tableHost);
var query = azure.TableQuery
    .select()
    .from('users')
    .where('PartitionKey eq ?', '0')
    .and('FriendsSeeVideo eq ?', 'true')
    .and('Status eq ?', 'Active');

var firstTimeThrough = true;
for (f in friends){
    if (firstTimeThrough){
        query.and('UserID eq ?', friends[f].id);
        firstTimeThrough = false;
    }
    else query.or('UserID eq ?', friends[f].id);
}
```

When I write the query to the screen I get an Azure Table Query that looks like this:

```
query = {"_fields":[],"_from":"users","_where":["PartitionKey eq '0'"," and FriendsSeeVideo eq 'true'"," and Status eq 'Active'"," and UserID eq '763424639'"," or UserID eq '1385552681'"," or UserID eq '100001386550915'"," or UserID eq '100001869159941'"],"_top":null,"_partitionKey":null,"_nextPartitionKey":null,"_rowKey":null,"_nextRowKey":null}
```

but it's not returning the result I expect.  There is 1 user that satisifies the conditions in table storage and the result should be returning the user with userID 763424639 but it's not?

Basically I am passing in a friend set and asking table storage if these people exist in the users table and to return them if they have enabled the FriendsSeeVideo setting.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It might be helpful to look at the request being sent to storage. See if you can get it from the Node SDK or with an http proxy like Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but perhaps you want to be using a boolean true rather than the string 'true'? It's hard to tell from this what's wrong... maybe you can show us the actual entity that you expect to be returned.

Comment: Taking a wild guess, I believe you're getting bit by logical operator precedence as everything goes as just one query. Can you try executing the first query, get it's result and then apply the 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the field [FriendsSeeVideo] by the wrong name it should have been [FriendsSeeVideoView].

I think I'll leave this question on SO because my example code can help somebody wondering how to compare and retrieve sets from table storage.